# Delete multiple array ranges giving runtime 1004 error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to setup a macro to read a string of tab names (ProductTabs) and then search the workbook. Once the ProductTabs = the workbook tab name, it will clear the contents from 2 different ranges.  I had it all manually coded, but its possible that additional tabs may be added. I'm stuck with getting the look to work correctly.  I get a runtime 1004 - Application defined or object defined error, when it hits this line of code: `Set ProductTabs = wb1.Sheets("tabNames").Cells(3, 2).Resize(1, lastcol - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)`

```
    Sub ResetBudget()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim addresses() As String
    Dim addresses2() As String
    Dim ProductTabs As Range, cell As Range
    Dim i As Long, lastcol As Long
    
    addresses = Strings.Split("B9,B12:B26,B32:B38,B42:B58,B62:B70,B73:B76,B83:B90", ",")
    addresses2 = Strings.Split("I9,I12:I26,I32:I38,I42:I58,I62:I70,I73:I76,I83:I90", ",")
    lastcol = wb1.Sheets("tabNames").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set ProductTabs = wb1.Sheets("tabNames").Cells(3, 2).Resize(1, lastcol - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    
    For Each cell In ProductTabs
        If CStr(wb1.Sheets("tabNames").Evaluate("ISREF('[" & wb1.Name & "]" & ProductTabs & "'!$A$1)")) = "True" Then
            For i = 0 To UBound(addresses)
                wb1.Sheets(ProductTabs).Range(addresses(i)).ClearContents
            Next i
        
        'wb1.Sheets("1061 ABAD-F").Range("B9,B12:B26,B32:B38,B42:B58,B62:B70,B73:B76,B83:B90").ClearContents
        'wb1.Sheets("1061 ABAD-F").Range("I9,I12:I26,I32:I38,I42:I58,I62:I70,I73:I76,I83:I90").ClearContents
        'wb1.Sheets("1062 TANF-F").Range("B9,B12:B26,B32:B38,B42:B58,B62:B70,B73:B76,B83:B90").ClearContents
        'wb1.Sheets("1062 TANF-F").Range("I9,I12:I26,I32:I38,I42:I58,I62:I70,I73:I76,I83:I90").ClearContents
        'wb1.Sheets("1063 Duals-F").Range("B9,B12:B26,B32:B38,B42:B58,B62:B70,B73:B76,B83:B90").ClearContents
        'wb1.Sheets("1063 Duals-F").Range("I9,I12:I26,I32:I38,I42:I58,I62:I70,I73:I76,I83:I90").ClearContents
        'wb1.Sheets("1064 CSHCS-F").Range("B9,B12:B26,B32:B38,B42:B58,B62:B70,B73:B76,B83:B90").ClearContents
        'wb1.Sheets("1064 CSHCS-F").Range("I9,I12:I26,I32:I38,I42:I58,I62:I70,I73:I76,I83:I90").ClearContents
        Else
            Debug.Print "A tab " & ProductTabs & " was not found in " & wb1.Name
        End If
    Next cell
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: `lastcol = wb1.Sheets("tabNames").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`

Comment: 2 things: the `Evaluate()` method throws an error if the string passed to it exceeds 255 characters, which is a distinct possibility when the string includes a workbook name (since a workbook name _can_ be longer than this), so I suggest you use the [revised syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72208389/timeline#history_85110e9b-8c04-47d2-aa20-bf5e812ed5e0) I originally provided. Secondly, you need to look at your loop - `cell` is your iteration variable, but you don't reference it _anywhere_ in the loop body.

Comment: @SpectralInstance I was trying to modify the code, but i couldn't figure out how to incorporate 2 different address strings and got the error message in the process. Sorry, I'm still new to VBA so I'm learning as I go. The string should never exceed 255, including spaces.

Comment: Ok, leaving `Evaluate()` aside, you will get another error with _that_ code, as you cannot have a tab named ProductTabs (because it is range comprising several cells)... you need to reference your loop-iteration variable, `cell`